# How to get image src cascaded inside div

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

Here is my xpath:

```
img =  hxs.xpath("//div[@class='gallery-images']/a//figure[@class = 'gallery-images-item']/img/@src").get()
```

Here is the link to page where I am checking this from :
https://www.michaelkors.com/allie-mixed-media-trainer/_/R-US_43T9ALFS3L

I have tried every combination but it is still returning None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website store all products details inside JSON structure (see `window.__INITIAL_STATE__` in the source) that's why you can't find it in HTML code. Also there are separate images for each available SKU (usually they are all the same), in my solution I use first SKU:

```
import scrapy
import json


class MichaelKorsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MichaelKors'
    start_urls = ['https://www.michaelkors.com/allie-mixed-media-trainer/_/R-US_43T9ALFS3L']

    def parse(self, response):

        initial_state = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ")]/text()').re_first(r'window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =\s*(\{.+?\});')
        data = json.loads(initial_state)

        images = []

        for image_url in data["pdp"]["rawJson"]["SKUs"][0]["media"]["images"]:
            images.append("https://michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/" + image_url)

        print(images)
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I hope my question doesn't sound silly but can you please direct me to how you got to know about these specific fields for data variable.

Comment: @Newbie Just checked source code, got JSON, and analyzed it.